"Why" is the sequence $a_k a_{k+2} = a_{k+1} + 1$ periodic?
Bit of a recreational math post (with an admittedly soft question). I (re)stumbled upon this via this USAMTS problem https://files.usamts.org/Problems_25_3.pdf
It turns out (spoilers) that the sequence $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ defined recursively by $a_k a_{k+2} = a_{k+1} + 1$ for $k \geq 3$ is periodic! The period is equal to 5.
You can see this by doing some algebra bashing (taking $a_3 = \frac{a_2 + 1}{a_1}$, then $a_4 = \frac{\frac{a_2 + 1}{a_1}+1}{a_2}$, and so forth). Things end up working out pretty magically. But I'm curious if there's some more enlightening reason why this sequence ends up repeating? Is there, say, some geometric way to see this? Are there other such sequences that behave this way?
Thanks in advance :)

I suspect group theory [ not geometry ] is involved here. We have to identify some Operation which makes elements $x_1,x_2$ have inverse elements $x_4,x_3$ while making $x_0$ the Identity element.

In the PDF, the problem numbers look like dates from the year 2025 (the future). But actually, 1/3/25 through 5/3/25 mean Problems 1 to 5 from Round 3 of Year 25 (which actually occurred 11 years ago), not the 3rd of January to May 2025 or the 1st to the 5th of March 2025.

I've no idea if this works, but because it's an order 2 recursion, have you considered the map that takes $(x_n,x_{n+1})$ to $(x_{n+1},x_{n+2})$, as a self-map of $\mathbb R^2$? It might have some nice property?

You can search for "pentagramma mirificum" and "Lyness 5-cycle" for the geometry. BTW, $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}/a_n$ is periiod $6$.

@GeoffreyTrang Haha yeah, kind of confusing. I put "re"stumbled upon because I did this contest in high school and was checking it out again.

This is the first example discussed in Fomin and Reading's Root systems and generalized associahedra, who call it the pentagon recurrence. It's one of the simplest examples of the Laurent phenomenon, and there's a lot of theory to dive into here, involving stuff like cluster algebras. I am not familiar with this but my understanding is that the recurrence ends up being a special case of what is called cluster mutation.
As Fomin and Reading note, the situation simplifies a lot if that $+1$ is removed, because then you can just take logarithms and you get a pretty straightforward linear recurrence, which turns out to be periodic of period $3$. But the $+1$s change the period to $5$!

the first one is a very nice read!

Thanks so much, that's so cool to hear there's a deeper theory behind this! I'll give your sources a read.
